# React Router 4 Nested Routes Clashing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have the following routes:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/:profileType/:profileId' component={Profile}/>
  <Route path='/about/:aboutThing' component={AboutThing}/>
</Switch>
```

When I try and go to `/about/:aboutThing` - it's recognized as a `{Profile}` route. This makes sense, as technically `:profileType` can be any string and thus any nested route will be recognized as a `Profile`.

I'm wondering if it's possible to render `{AboutThing}` without changing its route. Technically, `/about` should be a reserved word for that route. I tried doing:

`<Route exact path='/about/:aboutThing' component={AboutThing}/>`

But that didn't work either. Trying not to have to add an extra string in that path in order to make it work. Any thoughts/ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is pretty straight forward, `Switch` stops after the first matched route, so you could rearrange your routes like

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/about/:aboutThing' component={AboutThing}/>
  <Route path='/:profileType/:profileId' component={Profile}/>
</Switch>
```